# How to make the marker appear in the center of the Google Map initial window?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Maps V2 Android in my app.

I place a marker at the point of Singapore.

But I notice every time my app starts up, the initial window is somewhat always South America.

How may I make the map automatically zoom to Singapore area with the marker in the center?

I place the marker as follows:

```
googleMapLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(googleMapLocation).title("I am here!"));
```

Comment: `map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(googleMapLocation , zoom /*fx: 15.0f*/));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(googleMapLocation, zoom));
```